# How do we pass props to NavLink?

Tags: reactjs

How do I pass props to NavLink when linking from one component to another? Here's what I have

```
<NavLink to={`/mentor/${mentor.id}`} exact>Test</NavLink>
```

Comment: What is `NavLink`? Which navigation library are you using?

Comment: import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lacking `:` before the id, like so:

```
<NavLink to={`/mentor/:${mentor.id}`} exact>Test</NavLink>
```

Comment: This is not correct for react router